# Apache2 no longer restarts after 16.04 upgrade

Tags: apache2, 16.04

Upgraded to 16.04 yesterday on a machine with a fairly large number of packages installed.  Kudos for a generally smooth upgrade, `apache2` even kept running.

This morning, however, via the daily cronjob, it stopped with the following error (indented by hand for better readability):

```
[Sat May 14 07:35:30.676246 2016] [mpm_worker:notice] [pid 16811:tid 140122659370880] 
     AH00292: Apache/2.4.12 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sat May 14 07:35:30.676284 2016] [core:notice] [pid 16811:tid 140122659370880] 
     AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Sun May 15 07:35:46.274324 2016] [mpm_worker:notice] [pid 16811:tid 140122659370880] 
     AH00297: SIGUSR1 received.  Doing graceful restart
     apache2: Syntax error on line 141 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: 
              Syntax error on line 1 of /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/cgid.load: 
              Cannot load /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_cgid.so into server: 
              /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_cgid.so: 
              undefined symbol: ap_map_http_request_error
```

I "resolved" this for now by moving `cgid.conf` and `cgid.load` out of the `mods-enabled` directory.  But that can't be the best solution...

This machine has been upgraded probably over a dozen or so Ubuntu releases.  I should note that I haven't rebooted.  That wasn't always necessary so I skipped it here too.

Comment: I think you need to restart just to be sure the problem isn't it.